# pixel perfect images using monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

Background:

I need to get a basic understanding on how to present pixel perfect images on iOS devices using MonoTouch. My understanding of the iOS ecosystem is limited at the moment, being a developer for the windows platform for the last 18 years. From what I understand there is a common coordinate system that renders views the same no matter if it's a retina display or an old "iPhone 3g" display.

The question is:

What is the best way to generate and display images without blurring or distortion using MonoTouch?

// AnkMannen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing you need to learn about is iOS's system for the retina display.

All controls are laid out in coordinates as if they were a 3GS/iPad 2 or older. Devices with the retina display such as iPhone 4, 5, and iPad 3 all use these same coordinates, but with double the screen size.

For your images, use PNGs.  You will have 2 sets, one for the smaller display, and one for the retina display. Apple uses the file-naming convention:

- `yourImage.png` - smaller image for 3GS
- `yourImage@2x.png` - larger image for retina displays

Let's assume the image is 150 pixels by 50 pixels at the smaller size. To properly display it from C#:

```
//This code is in the ViewDidLoad method of a UIViewController
var imageView = new UIImageView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 150, 50));
imageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("yourImage.png");
View.AddSubView(imageView);
```

iOS will load the appropriate sized image (by the naming convention) and place it in the top left of the screen.  Keeping the correct size for the `imageView` will also prevent any distortion. On retina displays, iOS will load the larger 300x100 image and look identical (except much sharper) to the smaller sized screens side-by-side.